# Fibonacci Measurement Algorithm implementation: missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'

Tags: python, fibonacci

I've implemented a fibonacci Measurement algorithm with 2 parameter n and p.

I got this issue,

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-295638b26e62> in <module>
      2 N = 10
      3 # [F(n,p) for n in range(N)]
----> 4 print(F(10,1))

<ipython-input-12-fda62c8ec9a6> in F(n, p)
      6     elif n <= p+1:
      7       return n
----> 8     return F(n-1) + F(n-p-1)

TypeError: F() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'
```

I have input 2 parameters n =10, p = 1, but still having this problem "missing 1 required argument". Does anyone know why and solution for this or any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: You're calling some function F that you haven't shown us the definition of.  It apparently takes two arguments.

Comment: @FrankYellin my bad, I forget to change the name. I have fixed the question, could you check it?

Comment: is there any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be two potential issues.

1. You're calling a function, `F`, that doesn't seem to be defined in the snippet you've attached. You might want to change it to `fibonacci_of` if it is supposed to call itself recursively. In addition, since the `fibonacci_of` accepts two parameters, you would need to call it with two arguments
2. If `F` is already defined elsewhere, it is supposed to accept more than one argument. You could check its function definition and see the parameter requirements. See attached examples.

```py
def square(a): # Requires single parameter.
  return a ** 2
```

```py
def add(a, b): # Requires two parameters.
  return a + b
```

Comment: thanks for your comment! Sorry, I have fixed the question. Yes, I call the function F with 2 parameters F(10,1), but it does not work?

Comment: Did you try calling the following functions with two parameters? `return F(n-1) + F(n-p-1)` All the function calls should have two parameters.